# If there is only one document in a subcollection, what ID is the best to give the child document?

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-security

I have a Firestore collection that contains documents with a subcollection.
The subcollection is intended to keep **only one** document that has information related to the parent document.

***Collection - Document(parent) - Subcollection - Document(child)*** <-- (what ID??)

Since the parent document has become complex, I decided to refactor it into the structure shown above.
But I don't understand **what ID is the best** to give the child document.

Fixed ID or auto-generated ID or the parent document's ID?

What would you do when you have this kind of structure?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no objective best here, it all depends on the use-case and personal preference.

I typically call it something like `DEFAULT`, but any other name is just as good. What I find most important is that I can remember it, since this is one document that you tend to type in your code.

Comment: Yeah, I totally agree with this. But I've a doubt that it might take some backed work to generate unique id so providing a fixed id would be a better way.